# php и radiobutton

Tags: php, radio

Как обработать код так, чтобы после проверки radiobutton не пересылало на другой сайт, а всё оставалось на том же, ну то есть когда ты обрабатываешь radiobutton, то PHP после обработки автоматом пересылает тебя на пустой сайт, мне же нужно чтобы он просто перезагружал страницу и выводил ошибку если ни один radio не был выбран, как это реализовать?

HTML

```html
<input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка1" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №1
<input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка2" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №2
<input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка3" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №3
```

PHP

```
if (isset($radio) == false) {
        $error_radio = "Вы не выбрали чекбокс!";
```

}

Comment: PHP не посылает на другой сайт. Все делает программист. Если вам нужно найти ошибку в вашем коде, то логично было бы привести этот код

Comment: Я исправил главное сообщение, проверьте. Мне нужно чтобы код не пересылал меня на другую страницу, когда я проверяю к примеру type="text" такого нет, просто обновляется страница и всё. А тут идёт перессылка на другую страницу, чего мне не нужно

Comment: В приведенном коде нет никакой пересылки

Comment: Я про тоже, но меня пересылает, на пустой сайт, как вот в данном видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmyoiloSCIg
Тут человека переносит на другой сайт когда он нажимает на кнопку, мне же этого не нужно, я просто хочу чтобы PHP как нужно перезагрузил страницу и обработал данный запрос на данной же странице, прошу отметить что это всё в форме, все как нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В видеоуроке, на который Вы дали ссылку, данные формы отсылаются в файл `process.php`. Для того, чтобы данные отсылались на тот же скрипт, где расположена форма, нужно установить значение атрибута [action](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/action) формы как пустую строку.

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='send' value='1'>
    <input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка1" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №1
    <input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка2" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №2
    <input class="radio" type="radio" value="коробка3" name="radio-test"/>Чек бокс №3   
    <input type='submit' value='go!'>
</form>

<?php

@$send = $_POST['send'];

if ( $send )                               // форма отправлена?
{
    @$radio = $_POST['radio-test'];

    if( !$radio )                          // радиокнопка выбрана?
    {
        $error_radio = "Вы не выбрали чекбокс!";
        echo $error_radio;      
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Подавление ошибок (_я про оператор_ `@`) - это плохая практика. Есть нормальные способы проверки входящих данных.